# Python-Sqlalchemy Binary Column Type HEX() and UNHEX() with autoloaded table

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

We use sqlalchemy and inserts and updates works fine, but now we want migrate UUID from varchar to varbinary. How to do this?

Example of code now:

```
engine = create_engine(dburi, echo = True, pool_size=100, pool_recycle=7200)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=True, bind=engine))
metadata = MetaData(engine)
conn = engine.connect()
....
table = Table("table", metadata, autoload=True)
result = db_session.execute(table.insert(), {"uuid":func.UNHEX("AABBCCDD"})
```

In output i see

INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('unhex(:unhex_1)',) and in db - not result of UNHEX but UNHEX(:UNHEX_1)

I have seen [Python-Sqlalchemy Binary Column Type HEX() and UNHEX()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923914/python-sqlalchemy-binary-column-type-hex-and-unhex/33925980) but i cannot comment this and cannot understand what if we *load* structure, not generate it in class. Use db_sesson.execute().filter()? And how to updates when we need "where uuid=UNHEX(?)" ?

Now if i write as uuid=binascii.unhexlify(uuid), save to varbinary(32) - works, to varchar(64) with table charset=utf8 works, to carchar with charset=ascii - exception

```
OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xDB\\xE7,\\x98\\xF9\\x11...' for column 'uuid' at row 1") [SQL: u'INSERT INTO callrec (record_dt, dealer_id, client_id, extension_id, caller_id, destination, file_size, record_url, uuid, record_path, duration) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'] [parameters: (datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 2, 13, 33, 51), u'1', u'12', u'6', u'000*102', u'000*103', 67244, u'', 'P\xdb\xe7,\x98\xf9\x11\xe5\xb8\x9e\xd3\xb2v\xc0\xccZ', '', 2)]
```

But manual write as uuid=UNHEX("AABBCCDD") already works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are doing the insert wrongly, try this:

```
db_session.execute(table.insert().values(uuid=func.UNHEX("AABBCCDD")))
```

or this (very close to your statment):

```
stmt = table.insert().values(uuid=func.unhex(bindparam('hex')))
db_session.execute(stmt, {'hex': 'AABBCCDD'})
```

Also, if you want, you could use the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923914/python-sqlalchemy-binary-column-type-hex-and-unhex/33925980#33925980), in order to do this, just [override some columns](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/reflection.html#overriding-reflected-columns):

```
table = Table("model", metadata, 
        Column("uuid", HashColumn(20)), 
        autoload=True)
```

And execute the following instruction in order to insert without use of `func.*`:

```
db_session.execute(table.insert().values(uuid='AABBCCDD'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class HashColumn(VARBINARY):
  def bind_expression(self, bindvalue):
  #bindvalue = type_coerce(bindvalue, Binary)
  return func.unhex(func.replace(bindvalue, '-', ''))

  def column_expression(self, col):
    return func.lower(func.hex(col))

def select(table_name):
  table = Table(table_name, self.metadata, Column("uuid", HashColumn(20)), autoload=True, extend_existing=True)
  select = table.select()
  ...
```